Contributions not populating on Contact record tab
I have very recently updated CiviCRM from v5.76.1 to 5.78.0 and also updated PHP to the recommended v8.3
Wordpress is up to date on version 6.6.2
Since updating, the contribution tab on the contact record fails to populate, with message "
Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."
Refreshing the page fails to correct the problem
When attempting to search in 'Find contributions', an error message appears saying "  Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Syntax error in template "file:/var/www/vhosts/bluestrust.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contribute/Page/ContributionTotals.tpl" on line 19 "{if $contributionSummary.cancel.amount nofilter}" too many shorthand attributes"
Line 19 shows " {if $contributionSummary.cancel.amount nofilter}
   {ts}Cancelled/Refunded{/ts} – {$contributionSummary.cancel.amount nofilter}
{/if}"
I'm puzzled by such messages and wondering whether the updates I've performed have caused the issues.  Backdating PHP to v8.2 has not cured the problems.
Has anyone else had such issues please?

I have exactly the same system and issue: > ContributionTotals.tpl" on line 19 "{if

$contributionSummary.cancel.amount nofilter}" too many shorthand
attributes I tried to change ContributionTotals.tpl as described in Demerit's links and I tried to change Smarty version, but I still get the error.


Maybe clear cache?

The problem went away after updating CiviCRM to v 5.78.1 [Later update now available to v 5.78.2]

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5506 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/31233. You can apply that patch, or you can try smarty4 which your civi system status messages should have a message about.

Thank you Dermerit.........much appreciated
