In Recent Civicrm Update (5.78.0) No Contribution page not opening , it says Unable to connect with server . - Wordpress Site
My Civicrm version is on 5.77.0 I update it on 5.78.0 But After Updating The Contribution are not opening . It says Unable to connect with server. I have clear Cache ,it does not working but,All others things working fine , able to create a new contribution also seen in the Contribution in Activity . But Not seen in Contribution page

Hi, this seems like the same question as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/48713/contributions-not-populating-on-contact-record-tab. Check out the solution there.

This question is similar to: Contributions not populating on Contact record tab. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yeah, I have the same issue, and clearing cache did not help either. If you look in the PHP error logs, you'll see something like this:
PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in [....]/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%98/98F/98F6DF1D%%CMSUser.tpl.php on line 19
If you open that link up in a new window you'll get some content, but still a 'critical error has occurred' message which is why you see the network disconnect (web server logs would be an HTTP 500).
Haven't gotten any further in diagnosis (could be related to the DB changes during the upgrade?), so hopefully someone else will chime in or we'll get a 5.78.1 soon (before the upcoming security update at least).
Do you have the Smarty5 libraries loaded? From the system status info, that would be:
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH',
'/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty5/Smarty.php');
I do not (doing so causes immediate site crashes, could be a conflict with one of my extensions). I ask because that PHP file makes references to Smarty.

See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/48713/contributions-not-populating-on-contact-record-tab
